# Having a weird network issue

Tags: networking, apt, xubuntu

I am using xubuntu 14.04.02 on a new build. Networking works great except when accessing any ubuntu site. For example, I can stream several videos and pandora at the same time with no problem. When I try to add a package, it takes 30 minutes to connect and then goes through just like normal. I get ping of around mid 50's to us.archive.ubuntu.com and my browser connects immediately, but it takes 30 minutes (I timed it) to connect to it using "apt-get update". I have other systems on the same network and they don't have the issue. Other sites such as ppa.launchpad.net seem to work fine.

My build is a Asus M5A97R2 mobo with 16G of 1866Mhz RAM and a 1T main drive without LVM and a Geforce GTX750 video board. It's a UEFI install.

If anyone can help me get pointed in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The miror server must be slow. Just change the mirror to something else.